# NOT LIKE '%%' query on JSON data returns incorrect results

Tags: sql, json, azure-data-studio

I have this query:

```
select * 
from t
where 
    JsonColumn like '%A%' and
    JsonColumn not like '%"A": null%'
```

I can see that `JsonColumn` of several rows contains the value present in `not like` clause i.e. some json values contain this content:

```
{ "A": null }
```

Why are those rows not being filtered out?

---

For example, my `JsonColumn` could look like any of the below:

```
{ "A": "2022-10-20" }
{ "A": null }
{ }
```

So I will try to run the query `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE JsonColumn NOT LIKE '%"A": null%'`, and expect it to return only the first and third rows, since they don't contain `"A": null`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I am using Azure Data Studio if thats what you mean? It's an Azure-Hosted SQL Server

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the irrelevant details stripped out.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure which irrelevant details I've included? Are you saying you are unable to replicate this issue?

Comment: I have not tried to replicate the issue because a) it would be too much work, without having a setup similar to yours, and b) I am not asking this question on stackoverflow; you are.  The irrelevant details are the identifiers you are using.  Identifiers in a question should be "A", "B", "C" or "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie" etc.

Comment: In any case, the irrelevant details" part is itself a detail. Ignore that. Just provide a minimal reproducible example showing sample data, a query, what you expected it to yield, what it actually yields.

Comment: (Many chances are you will find your problem by yourself while creating the minimal reproducible example.)

Comment: @MikeNakis I updated the question, but not sure if its clearer or not. Seems I miss some fundamental understanding of sql

Comment: It may be that you miss some fundamental understanding of sql, or it may be that your fundamental understanding is fine but you have just a slight misunderstanding somewhere, or it may be that you have no misunderstandings at all, but you simply have a typo somewhere.  The problem is, we do not know which one is the case. That's why minimal reproducible examples are important. I could start asking questions like "how is your table defined" but it would be a lot easier if you re-create your problem on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post a link.

Comment: ^^^ that would be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MikeNakis The problem is, I feel like my example is minimal reproducible - I have included all the key components of my issue, and example data, and described teh problem, which is essentially why is `LIKE` ignoring my `"`s. I will try to add a sql fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to handle JSON data:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select *
    from openjson(jsoncolumn)
    where [key] = 'A' and value is not null
)
```

Note that you cannot use the simpler `JSON_VALUE` function here since it can not differentiate between a key containing `null` and a key that does not exist (without throwing an error).

Comment: Thanks Salman, your answer led me to a solution - I just needed to change it to `WHERE EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

You must use like this you can check your column for null using Like in sql. It will return the records which are not like DateOnBlacklist.

```
select * from [dbo].[EntityChanges] where BaselineJsonString not like coalesce('%DateOnBlacklist%',null)
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I want records where the column does not contain `"DateOnBlacklist": "`, but does have the `DAteOnBlacklist` somehwere in it. not ones where there is no `DateOnBlacklist` mentioned at all